# SQL queries are pulling everything?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, minecraft

This is a plugin for minecraft. It is supposed to pull the players with the customer ID set in the config and display them ingame. It instead pulls everyone, no matter what their customer ID is.

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getaward"))
    {
        Player player = (Player)sender;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,dbUser,dbPass);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `votesdb` WHERE `nick` = '"+player.getName().substring(0,player.getName().length()/2)+"' AND `customer_id` LIKE "+config.getString("customer_id")+"");
    //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT nick,votes FROM `votesdb` WHERE nick='"+player.getName()+" LIMIT 1");
    if(rs.next())
    {
        if(rs.getInt("votes")!=0)
        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN+"[VFD]"+ChatColor.AQUA+"Thanks for voting! You will find something special in your inventory. :)");
            bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GREEN+"[VFD]"+ChatColor.AQUA+player.getDisplayName()+" has been rewarded for Voting for the Server!");
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE `votesdb` SET flag=0 WHERE `nick` LIKE '"+player.getDisplayName().substring(0,player.getDisplayName().length()/2)+"'");
            player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(this.matID,this.matAmt));


        }
        else
        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"You have already claimed your reward.");
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"We could not find you in the database! Please make sure you used the correct name when you voted!");
    }
```

Comment: IF custormer Id is unique then y dont you use equals (`customer_id` =config.getString("customer_id")) instead of like....

Comment: is that my problem? do i need to use = instead of like?

Comment: Have you checked that `player.getName().substring(0,player.getName().length()/2)` does indeed return the player's nick? Looks to me like it deliberately returns half of it! (Also, if a nickname or a customer ID is unique, then use just the unique one - another one is just overhead).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make you query as simple as possible, see that it works, and only then build towards your goal.
2. It doesn't make sense to have any other condition besides the customer ID. You said you need all players with that customer ID.
3. As already noted, ID's are supposed to be constrained to a single value, not to be LIKE some string.